# Updating data in two related tables using GraphDiff

Tags: c#, entity-framework, graphdiff

I have two tables, Order and OrderItems

The Order table has a OrderId column that's the primary key
The OrderItems also has this column as foriegn key.

For a given Order, if the OrderId is 1 and it has two items the OrderItems table
will have two rows each having OrderID as 1.

Using EF I created a context with the two tables.

Now the Order table and OrderItems table both have a Status column.

Using GraphDiff I wanted to update this value likes so:

```
using (var ordersContext = new OrdersContext())
{
    ordersContext.UpdateGraph(orderToUpdate, map => map.OwnedCollection(p => p.OrderItems));
    ordersContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This gives the following exception:

```
GraphDiff supports detached entities only at this time. Please try AsNoTracking() or detach your entites before calling the UpdateGraph method
```

Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means most likely that orderToUpdate or related properties are attached to the context or another instance of the context already. You need to look at how you retrieve or produce orderToUpdate before calling this code.

for example if you do

```
var ordersContext = new OrdersContext();
var orderToUpdate = ordersContext.Find(orderToUpdateId); // id of what is looked for
orderToUpdate.DateCreated = DateTime.Now; // any sort of update
```

then in that case I believe the object is still attached due the exception;